# How to follow the cursor with Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, animation, mouse, angular-animations

I created a simple application ([StackBlitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-move-eye)) in Angular with animations.
It uses states that we can toggle to make an eye look wherever we want.

Now I would like to be able to follow the mouse cursor using pure Angular/TypeScript (not jQuery...), so the eye would look to the cursor's direction whenever the mouse is moving.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use @HostListener decorator.
[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-move-eye-vsusey) is live example

Comment: This was a very good idea, and it works. The problem is that there is only 4 positions (topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight) when we do it like this. I really would like the eye to be able to follow the cursor. It means it could rotate between topLeft and bottomLeft (31° instead of 45° for example). Is it more clear ?